# How to import data from Excel to mysql Database in Laravel? (php, laravel, mysql)

Tags: php, excel, laravel

[Update: csv file is succeed in importing data to mysql database, but xls/xlsx still got 'Undefined offset: 1' error]

When I input the Excel file and submit it to import, what I got is error 'Undefined offset: 1'

When I do `dd($row)` what I got is somehow working?

> array:3 [▼   0 => 1   1 => "XI TKJ"   2 => "Kelas XI TKJ" ]
> [Screenshot of dd($row) result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cgC7p.png)

##### Error:

[image: Error Screenshot]

##### Data in excel I want to input:

[image: Excel data]

Apparently, there's already data on the table but I don't know if it would affect the result or not:

[image: Table]

File that got the error -> `jurusanImport.php`(updated)

```
use App\jurusan;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToModel;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithMultipleSheets;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithConditionalSheets;

class jurusanImport implements ToModel
{
    /**
    * @param array $row
    *
    * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model|null
    */
    use WithConditionalSheets;
    public function conditionalSheets(): array
    {
        return [
            'Worksheet 1' => new FirstSheetImport(),
            'Worksheet 2' => new SecondSheetImport(),
            'Worksheet 3' => new ThirdSheetImport(),
        ];
    }
    public function model(array $row)
    {
        dd($row);
        return new jurusan([
            'nama_jurusan' => $row[1],
            'deskripsi' => $row[2],
        ]);
    }
}
```

##### `web.php`

```
Route::post('/Admin/Jurusan/import_excel', 'AdminController@import_Jurusan')
    ->middleware('role:Admin');
Route::get('/admin/Jurusan/List', 'AdminController@showJurusanList')
    ->middleware('role:Admin');
```

##### `AdminController.php`

```php
public function import_Jurusan(Request $request) 
    {
    $user = Auth::user();
    $this->validate($request, [
        'file' => 'required|mimes:csv,xls,xlsx'
    ]);
    $file = $request->file('file');
    $nama_file = rand().$file->getClientOriginalName();
    $file->move('file_teacher',$nama_file);
    $import = new jurusanImport;
    $import->onlySheets('Worksheet 1');
    Excel::import($import, public_path('/file_teacher/'.$nama_file));
    Session::flash('sukses','Data Siswa Berhasil Diimport!');
    return redirect()->back();
    }
    public function showJurusanList(Request $request)
    {
        $user = Auth::user(); // Untuk Photo Profile
        $jurusan = jurusan::get(); // Show, atau Get All "Materi"
        return view('pages.admin.kelas.showjurusan', compact('jurusan', 'user') );
    }
```

##### Model `jurusan.php`

```
protected $fillable = [
    'nama_jurusan', 'deskripsi', 
];

protected $table = 'jurusan';
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: you mean you want to do Data Import from CSV File Right?

Comment: What does `$row` have ? Do `dd($row)` before `return new jurusan([` on `jurusanImport` and check why `$row` does not have index `1`...

Comment: regular excel, so xlsx or xls extension. Already try it using csv extension too, fails to import data but  not show any error but back to table page.  for dd($row), what I got is this: 
array:3 [▼
  0 => 1
  1 => "X TKJ"
  2 => "Kelas X TKJ"
]

Comment: Tried csv file, it was a success with the help of answer from other. Tried xls/xlsx file, got error 'Undefined offset: 1' ...  Do dd($row) gets: array:3 [▼
  0 => 1
  1 => "XI TKJ"
  2 => "Kelas XI TKJ"
]

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple sheet in your xls file. You can check https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/imports/multiple-sheets.html#selecting-sheets-by-worksheet-index

This is not your actual code. I am just sharing to you for reference.

```
namespace App\Imports;

use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithMultipleSheets;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithConditionalSheets;

class UsersImport implements WithMultipleSheets 
{
    use WithConditionalSheets;

    public function conditionalSheets(): array
    {
        return [
            'Worksheet 1' => new FirstSheetImport(),
            'Worksheet 2' => new SecondSheetImport(),
            'Worksheet 3' => new ThirdSheetImport(),
        ];
    }
}
```

and in controller

```
$import = new UsersImport();
$import->onlySheets('Worksheet 1', 'Worksheet 3');

Excel::import($import, 'users.xlsx');
```

Comment: what I need is actually only one sheet(active one)... so something like this maybe useless for me, but I appreciate the help

Comment: Then you can remove the other sheet from the xls file then then you can try. Your code looks good.

Comment: But now I got this error Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalThrowableError (E_ERROR)
Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Session' not found

Comment: Oh well, maybe try the sheet too for now.

Comment: failed, it's still getting undefined offset: 1

Comment: what is the output of `dd($row)`?

Comment: array:3 [▼
  0 => 1
  1 => "X TKJ"
  2 => "Kelas X TKJ"
]

Comment: data from csv file can be imported, but xlsx or xls failed/